# How to store images in google drive through salesforce

Tags: visualforce, integration, google-drive

Actually my requirement is want to store bulk of images for these we can use document/notes and attachments due to storage constraint i want to use google drive to store the images from visualforce page/salesforce can any one help me how can i achieve this and what are the steps i have to follow.

Thanks in advance,
Chandra.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plenty of app exchange apps to save Google Drive.
We use one such app.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000008amNrEAI

If you gonna go with standard solutions, Summer 15 has provided solution to connect with Google Drive.
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_chatter_files_connect_google_drive.htm

http://www.summa.com/blog/salesforce-summer-15-feature-integrate-google-drive-in-minutes

Comment: Hi Pranay, you are right but here i don't want to use any apps

Comment: You can go with standard approach...
http://www.summa.com/blog/salesforce-summer-15-feature-integrate-google-drive-in-minutes

Comment: Hi Pranay, i followed standard approach i done all the configuration but i am getting 'You are not authorized to perform that operation'.can any one help me on this.